# Phonegap Body Larger than Screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, screen, viewport

I'm developing an Android App with Phonegap and JQueryMobile which require the use of $("#img1").css("bottom", "0px") to align to the bottom of the page...

When I test it in AVD (Nexus 4 and Nexus 7) it's perfect. When I put it into a phone I see that the "bottom" image it's more downwards than the screen and realize that I can actually scroll with my fingers to and can see the whole image.

Here is some (I think) relevant code

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Also may interest that the App is forced to be in landscape but I don't really think this is the problem...

Comment: The page or content size is probably set in pixels. Add (@media screen and (orientation: landscape)
.ui-mobile .ui-page {
min-height: 100% !important;
}) to your css and see if that makes a difference. In any case its a Css issue. If it doesnt work add the HTML code in your question to have a look at the structure you have. All you need for the viewport meta tag is (<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">)

Comment: Thanks, Tasos, I feel you are right but didn't understand you exactly. The content size actually IS in pixels (what other options I have?). (I0m going to try the @media suggestion and get back)

Comment: I added the @media line but the same result... BTW shouldn't be better max-height=100%???

Comment: yeah that's true, you can leave the min in there and add the max also. What you need to do is plug in an android device to a PC and check the CSS on the developer console. That's the only way you going to know whats happening with the screen size.  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Ok. I modified your @media and added a pair of brackets like this: (ATmedia screen and (orientation: landscape) {.ui-mobile .ui-page { min-height: 100% !important; }} and seems to work in some pages but not in others (JQueryMobile project)... please, post this as an anwser and we'll continue to discuss it there, ok?

Comment: the "AT" means the AT SYMBOL (didn't let me put it, don't know why...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its to do with JQM's min-height css setting on orientation landscape at page load. Try

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) .ui-mobile .ui-page { min-height: 100% !important; })
```

Comment: I embraced de css code in "{" and it worked in the first page, but not in others... I'm trying to figure it out what is it...

Comment: If you have a mobile device (Android) plug it in to a PC and check the CSS in the dev console to see whats happening. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging -- other than that if you have page id's try the CSS code and remove (.ui-mobile .ui-page) and add the page id's there to see if that helps